# How to call vf page in script tag

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, community

I want to call visualforce page ad a popup on click.

I tried to do it like . Can I call visualforce page in java script like ?

Comment: Can I add vf url in id like id="abcd.html"
<script type="text/ng-template" id="abcd.html">

Answer (score 1):

Ya you can use **window.open** javascript function..

on click of button write this code :

```
window.open('../apex/YourPage?id={!object__c.Id}', '_blank');
```

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 1):

you can use Window.open() :

```
var url = '/apex/popup?parameter='+ val ;
newWin = window.open(url, 'Popup', 'height=500,width=600,left=100,top=100,resizable=no,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no,status=no');
```